# draw line at center of circle and join another three circle to form a square

Tags: java

I'm trying to draw line from center of one circle to another placed at distance of 50.

Also how to determine that four circle at the four corner is joined by lines and form a square where we can write text.

Similar diagram I would like to have.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MousePanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener,ActionListener{

    private int a,b,a2,b2;
    private int count=0;
public MousePanel(){
    super();
    addMouseListener(this);   
}

public void paint(Graphics g){


    for(int x=5;x<=1000; x=x+50){
        for(int y=5; y<=1000;y=y+50){
    g.drawOval(x,y,15,15);
            System.out.println(x+" "+y);
        }

    }
    if(count==2){
        if(a2>a){
        g.drawLine(a, b, a+50, b);
        }
        else{
            g.drawLine(a, b, a, b+50);
        }
    count=0;
    a=0;
    b=0;
    a2=0;
    b2=0;
    }
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouse){   

    count++;

    if(count==1){
        a=mouse.getX();

        b=mouse.getY();

        System.out.println(a+" "+b);
    }

    if(count==2){
        a2 = mouse.getX();
        b2 = mouse.getY();
         System.out.println(a2+" "+b2);
    }

    repaint();
    }

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent mouse){ }   
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent mouse){ }
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouse){ }
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mouse){ }

public static void main(String arg[]){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("MousePanel");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(640,640);

    MousePanel panel = new MousePanel();
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

This is my code. 
Here I have just made the coicle.

[image]

Comment: The main question here is purely geometrical and has nothing to do with Java, so you might consider using different tags so that the appropriate people see it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to answer your first question, but I may help you with your second. To determine if the centers of four circles are the corners of a square, the corners must be a certain distance from each other. First, select a corner. Then measure the distance the other points are away from the selected one. Assuming the square has a length of X, two of the distances will be X and one of them will be the sqrt(2)*X.

To determine the distance between two points, you use pythagorean theorem.

```
xDistance = point1.x - point2.x;
yDistance = point1.y - point2.y;
distance = sqrt(xDistance*xDistance + yDistance*yDistance);
```